# Ubuntu 14.04 and Android Studio 2.x Crashlytics (Fabric) plugin too slow

Tags: android, android-studio, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

Since upgrading to Studio 2.0 Crashlytics plugin became really unresponsive and slow, I can wait up to 15 minutes for it to unfreeze. It often freezes after "turn on", login or "Upload file" actions, without errors or any notifications. What may be causing the problem? Can i force some logging to get to the root of the issue?